# Get Instance of the same type using polymorphism

Tags: c#, architecture, polymorphism

I have the next scenario:
There is a class responsible to manage all the currencies of the application. All the currencies extend Currency so it can behave like it. Currency is abstract so it can not be instantiated.
In some parts of the application I have soft, hard, or event currencies as cost currency, for example, the player presses some purchase button on some menu. This action triggers a purchase, the purchase has currency as a reference, in this example it can be costSoftCurrency.
The idea is that if PlayerCurrencies receive a Currency, player currencies evaluate his currencies and return the associated currency of the same type and then you can subtract securely the cost.

My question is... how can I get the same logic without this horrible ifs? I read about [double dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) but I don't know if it can be applied here.

Does anyone know if this can be achieved?

```cs
public class PlayerCurrencies
{
    public SoftCurrency softCurrency = new SoftCurrency();
    public HardCurrency hardCurrency = new HardCurrency();
    public EventCurrency eventCurrency = new EventCurrency();

    public Currency GetCurrencyFromType(Currency currency)
    {
        if (currency is SoftCurrency)
        {
            return this.softCurrency;
        }

        if (currency is HardCurrency)
        {
            return this.hardCurrency;
        }

        if (currency is EventCurrency)
        {
            return this.eventCurrency;
        }

        return null;
    }
}

public abstract class Currency
{
    public float Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void Add(Currency currency)
    {
        this.Value += currency.Value;
    }

    public void Substract(Currency currency)
    {
        this.Value -= currency.Value;
    }
}

public class EventCurrency : Currency
{

}

public class HardCurrency : Currency
{

}

public class SoftCurrency : Currency
{

}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PlayerCurrencies playerCurrencies = new PlayerCurrencies();

        Currency costSoftCurrency = new SoftCurrency();
        Currency costHardCurrency = new HardCurrency();

        playerCurrencies.GetCurrencyFromType(costSoftCurrency).Substract(costSoftCurrency); // there i get a SoftCurrency from Player Currencies 
        playerCurrencies.GetCurrencyFromType(costHardCurrency).Substract(costHardCurrency); // there i get a HardCurrency from Player Currencies 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like something that visitor design pattern could help with

Comment: You could maintain a collection of each of the different currencies. And then to retrieve the currency by type you can use `.OfType()`

Comment: Tbh the whole different classes for different currencies and then messing around with types seems like over engineering. Functionality wise there is no difference between the currencies, so for me it feels there should just be one class. Create an `enum` to differentiate between your different currency types and pass that in it's constructor (make it a readonly field) and keep a `Dictionary<CurrencyType, Currency>` in the `PlayerCurrencies` class to give direct access to the different currencies: `return playerCurrencies[currency.Type];`

Comment: Something is off. You're passing a `Currency` as a parameter, but you don't care about its value. You only care about its type. This would be functionally the same if you changed it to `GetCurrencyFromType(Type currencyType)` and passed `currency.GetType()` to it instead of `currency`. This looks like something that should be generic, but we don't know how it's being called. It's best to design something like this from the point of view of the code that calls it. If we know what it needs to do, we can help describe something that does that (maybe.)

Comment: @ScottHannen if I change the type of Currency to Type as you suggested and then the `if(type is SoftCurrency)` is never triggered, the `GetCurrencyFromType(Type type)` always return null. The correct way to refactor this to a Type var is checking with `if(type == typeof(SoftCurrency)` to preserve the same functionality.

Comment: @Moutabreath yeah this way seems the more flexible and scalable, need a little bit of code set up all to work and multiple class, but seems the best approach.

Comment: If you made that change, the comparison would be different. A `Currency` is never a type, so none of those would ever match. Ignore what I said about that. It wasn't helpful and just added some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the factory method design pattern for this as it’s specifically for times when you are using subclasses to figure out what classes should be created. That’s basically what you’re doing here. My initial answer mentioned reflection because I saw the mapping config on the website I link to and thought that was cool, but after thinking it over last night it also has a lot of overhead. It would be much less complicated and faster to bypass an if block or switch statement by using a Dictionary.

This is what I would add/change about your code:

```
//The Factory class that creates the different types of currency based
//on a name parameter
static class CurrencyFactory
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, Currency> _currencyDictionary =
        new Dictionary<string, Currency>
    {
        { "HardCurrency", new HardCurrency() },
        { "SoftCurrency", new SoftCurrency() },
        { "EventCurrency", new EventCurrency() }
    };

    public static Currency Create(string currencyTypeName)
    {
        return _currencyDictionary[currencyTypeName];
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //This class will no longer be needed as it is redundant
        PlayerCurrencies playerCurrencies = new PlayerCurrencies();

        var costSoftCurrency = CurrencyFactory.Create("softCurrency");
        var costHardCurrency = CurrencyFactory.Create("hardCurrency");

        //I wasn't sure of your goals here so I kept it as is,
        //but as I said above, playerCurrencies won't be needed.
        playerCurrencies.GetCurrencyFromType(costSoftCurrency)
            .Substract(costSoftCurrency); // there i get a SoftCurrency from Player Currencies 

        playerCurrencies.GetCurrencyFromType(costHardCurrency)
            .Substract(costHardCurrency); // there i get a HardCurrency from Player Currencies 
    }
}
```

You can find a more thorough example and a great explanation of the pattern here: https://dev.to/gary_woodfine/how-to-use-factory-method-design-pattern-in-c-3ia3

Comment: It is not a good practice to send people to see other examples without adding an example of your own to demonstrate what they need to do. URL's attend to change and break with time.

Comment: Ah thank you, I’m new to answering. I’ll write up an example when I have time later today.

Comment: And it is great you invest your time to do so! The SO community try to improve first answer by reviewing them and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching):

```
public class PlayerCurrencies
{
    public SoftCurrency Soft = new SoftCurrency();
    public HardCurrency Hard = new SoftCurrency();
    public EventCurrency Event = new EventCurrency();

    public Currency GetCurrencyFromType(Currency currency)
    {
        switch (currency)
        {
            case EventCurrency: return Event;
            case HardCurrency: return Hard;
            case SoftCurrency: return Soft;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

I changed the names of the fields to `Hard`, `Soft`, and `Event` to more easily distinguish them from the types with the same names.

In this particular example it seems odd to pass in the `currency` parameter and only use it for its type. There might be another way to solve your specific problem. But as for how to do it without multiple `if` statements, that's how you can do it.

You'll most often see this demonstrated with variables declared, as follows:

```
switch (currency)
{
    case EventCurrency ec : return Event;
    case HardCurrency hc: return Hard;
    case SoftCurrency sc: return Soft;
}
return null;
```

For example, if the type of `currency` was `EventCurrency` then within the scope of the `case`, `ec` would be the `currency` argument cast as `EventCurrency`. But since in this example you're not using the value there's no need for the variables.